# cryptography book or resource

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin-literature

I am trying to write a multiple currency hd wallet.
I am using javascript libraries but I feel unsafe as I am new to most cryptography concepts and terms like elliptic curve, seeds, entropy etc.

I can not be a cryptography expert but I want to learn terms and concepts at least to know what it is doing when I am using third party libraries.

Can you recommend any books or online resources?

Answer (score 1):

Mastering Bitcoin is an amazing book that'll definitely get you started. It's freely available online here: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html

Comment: Thanks Tony. I know the book. But except chapter 4, it is more about blockchain and bitcoin rather than cryptography.

Comment: ah ok. I don't really have any good cryptography book recommendations but I am also interested in the answer to this question. I just figured Chapter 5 would help with the HD wallet part of your project :)

Answer (score 0):

Title:
Blockchain Enabled Applications

Subtitle:
Understand the Blockchain Ecosystem and How to Make it Work for You

Authors:
Dhillon, Vikram, Metcalf, David, Hooper, Max